# Double elements in Python Numpy Array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to copy every element into a 2d array in Python such that it doubles the size of the array and adds the element directly after the element that it intends to copy.

For example:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

becomes

```
[[1,1,2,2,3,3],
 [4,4,5,5,6,6],
 [7,7,8,8,9,9]]
```

Can anyone help with this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`np.repeat(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.repeat(a, 2, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]])
```

We thus repeat, for the second axis (`axis=1`) the elements two times.

We can also use list-comprehension, but given that the data has the same time, using `numpy` is faster, and more *declarative*:

```
times2 = [[xi for x in row for xi in [x, x]] for row in a]
```

This the produces:

```
>>> [[xi for x in row for xi in [x, x]] for row in a]
[[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6], [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a ton! I appreciate it. :-]